# class of all finite unions of closed-open intervals on the real line is a ring

Tags: real-analysis

lets say we have class of non-empty set V in the form of :

V={ $\cup_{i=1}^{n}\ \left[a_i{,}\ b_i\right); a_i{,}\ b_i\in \ R\ {,}\ n\in \ N\ $  }

So we have to show that this class of non-empty set is a ring. According to the definition of Ring, if we can manage to show

1.) $E$ $\cup$ $F$ $\in $ V where $E,F$ $\in $ V

2.) $E - F$ $\in $ V where $E,F$ $\in $ V

I understood the union part, I'm having difficulty proving the difference. So lets say in this case

$E - F$ = ($\cup_{i=1}^{n}\left[a_{i\ }{,}b_i\right) \cap  ( \cup_{i=1}^{m}\left[c_{j\ }{,}d_j\right)'$)

I'm completely using my professor's notes, so in order to demonstrate that the above expression is indeed a finite union of bounded, left closed right open intervals, he considered some arbitrary set $E_1$, $E_2$, $F_1$ & $F_2$ to prove his point.

So according to $E - F$ = $E$ $\cap$  $F^{'}$ we have:

($E_1$ $\cup$  $E_2$) $\cap$ ($F_1$ $\cup$  $F_2$ )' <--- (here i think my professor completely forgot to implement the complement inside the F sets, which is why i could not refer to his notes further but i corrected the mistake and carried forward) I ended up with this after expanding:

{($E_1$ $\cap$  $F_1$') $\cap$ (($E_1$ $\cap$  $F_2$')} $\cup$ {($E_2$ $\cap$  $F_1$') $\cap$ (($E_2$ $\cap$  $F_2$')}

My problem is that this expression is not necessarily forming finite union of bounded, left closed right open intervals because ($E_1$ $\cap$  $F_1$') and ($E_1$ $\cap$  $F_2$') themselves are indeed forming a closed-open intervals  respectively but the intersection between them is not necessarily forming a closed-open intervals to my logic, especially if there is nothing in common. And that would end up giving me a null/empty which we don't want. I'm really stuck in this part. I would really appreciate if someone can slowly make walk me through this problem again please